# how to download .ipa file as an email attachment in iPAD itself

Tags: ios, ipad, ipa

I want to send my .ipa file as an email attachment and download it in the iPAD itself using internet(safari) for testing purpose.My device-UDID has been registered with the provisioning profile.Is this possible?If it is possible ,Shall I be able to install it in my iPAD or moving it int iTunes?

I am very much new to iOS native application development.Please guide me to achieve this?Thanks for any help in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

First in iTunesconnect you have to register your device. This I think you have done.

Now create a adhoc distribution key and certificate by selecting your device in the provisioning portal.
Now create the .app file using the above mentioned adhoc certificate.
This app file you can mail and then copy the app file to itunes. 
It will be automatically installed to your iPad.

Comment: :For creating this adhoc distribution key and certificate what all things are required?Please help me to procced

Comment: Just login to Apple provisioning portal. Apple software comes with very good documentation. Its too good.

Answer (score 7):

You can upload you .ipa file either to [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com) or You can make use of this website also.

http://www.diawi.com

Both sites will help you getting the IPA file instantly. Hope that helps.